# Sending a JavaScript function from client to server with node.js + socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want my client to specify a predicate function that returns True or False based on an argument to the function.  The server takes this function and applies it to some data.

The solution I've come up with is not a nice one.  I use the browser's function.toString() method and call eval() on the server side.  Aside from the obvious security implications, it doesn't seem clean.

I am using socket.io for communication, and passing objects is completely seamless.  Is there a way to do this for functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is https://github.com/substack/dnode . It doesn't use .toString at all, but will let you call remote functions and get the results in a natural way. Check out the examples!

Edit: I forgot to mention, dnode uses socket.io underneath.

Comment: This looks great, but is there a way to define a function on the client side and have the server run it?  All the examples I see are server-side functions.

Comment: Yes it is possible, Now.JS does it. And it uses socket.io under the hood also.

Comment: dnode uses SockJS and not socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel here, [Dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) is exactly what you're looking for, since you can remotely call functions between server-client:

Example:

**server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8080);
console.log('http://localhost:8080/');

// then just pass the server app handle to .listen()!

var dnode = require('dnode');
var server = dnode({
    zing : function (n, cb) { cb(n * 100) }
});
server.listen(app);
```

**client**

```
...
    window.onload = function () {

        DNode.connect(function (remote) {
            remote.zing(66, function (n) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = n;
            });
        });

    };
```

Checkout more examples here: https://github.com/substack/dnode/tree/master/examples

Nice tutorial about DNode here: http://substack.net/posts/85e1bd/DNode-Asynchronous-Remote-Method-Invocation-for-Node-js-and-the-Browser